# Should words be capitalized because they're loanwords?

Tags: capitalization

In the English language Wikipedia article on [noh theatre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noh), "Noh" is frequently capitalized even when it's in the middle of a sentence. The only reason I could see someone doing that deliberately is because it's a loanword from Japanese. (The other possibility is that some of the authors are writing in English as a second language, but I doubt that's the explanation)

Assuming that italics are available, should words be capitalized because they're loanwords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, loanwords as a rule aren't capitalized, and they shouldn't be capitalized just because they're loanwords.

*Noh*, however, is sometimes viewed as a proper name for a type of Japanese drama. Proper names are capitalized in English. That's the only explanation. Italics aren't always available, especially in databases.

There's another Japanese word, *Go*, for 囲碁 (igo) (圍棋 wéiqí in Chinese), the [board game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) with black and white stones. The name of this game is also capitalized because it's the same as a very common English verb. This distinguishes *Go* the Chinese/Japanese board game from *go* the English verb, which is never capitalized unless it comes at the beginning of a sentence. Sometimes this word is spelled *Goe* and *Igo*.

Comment: Great reference to *Go.*  I came across a difficult analogy that only worked if the name of the game were capitalized.

Comment: @livresque: I lived in Tokyo for 10 years, played Go for 8, was married to a PRC Chinese Go player for 4 years, & used to edit & sell Go books & equipment about 20 years ago.