# Must the "b" in "Boolean variable" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the word Boolean be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/should-the-word-boolean-be-capitalized)

I notice that many online articles geared toward programmers refer to *boolean variables*, which are variables that have only two states: true or false. Is this correct usage? I'd contend that the "b" in Boolean should be capitalized because the term *Boolean* is named after mathematician [George Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole).

More generally, are there any grammatically correct examples of terms named after someone that are no longer capitalized?

Answer (score 1):

The first example that comes to mind is the word "xerox" which is typically not capitalized.

> "Can you xerox these documents for me so I can send copies to my parole officer?"

Another is "hoover"

> "He hoovered up his food like he hadn't eaten in weeks."

Both are capitalized in dictionaries, but usage examples don't always feature capitalization.

Comment: Does it matter that those are brand names and are not names of a person?

Comment: I don't really know. They are proper nouns which one would think ought to be capitalized.

Comment: Those are nouns that have transitioned into verbs - like Google and google. Whereas Boolean logic isn't (at least, I haven't ever come across 'to bool')

Comment: They are nouns as well: a copy is a xerox and a vacuum cleaner is a hoover even when they aren't actually the right brand.

Comment: Both 'xerox' and 'hoover' are specific examples of genericised names - things that used to be brand names and are now used generically ('hoover' much more so in the UK than North America). That's why they don't have caps.